# Iptables: how to drop incoming pings from host but allow ping responses?

Tags: firewall, iptables, ping

I am practicing with iptables and... I need a rule that will block a certain host from pinging me but will let me to ping the host if needed (so I need to accept ping responses right?). Can you help me?

Comment: Some context, please. What is your current `iptables` ruleset (the output of `iptables-save`) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can block ping (icmp echo requests) from all hosts using this

```
iptables -I INPUT -j DROP -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request
```

If you want to block a particular host then

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.1.139 -j DROP -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow single ip using

> iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

Now drop ICMP packets from rest

> iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP

Reference http://www.trickylinux.net/ping-single-ip-linux/

Answer (score 0):

If we start with everything blocked:
Allow OUTPUT ICMP (to host only if you like)
allow established ICMP connections INPUT (from host only if you like)